# Jasmine (ES6) can't find package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, jasmine

I'm using Exercism to learn Javascript, and with each exercise, a .spec.js file is provided, and they tell me to run it with Jasmine. I globally installed jasmine-es6 via npm, and when I run it, it errors out that it cannot find a package.json in the directory from which I am running the command:

```
ken@sub-zero:~/exercism/javascript/rna-transcription$ jasmine rna-transcription.spec.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-es6/node_modules/esnext-async/lib/main.js:45
              throw _context.t0;
              ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/ken/exercism/javascript/rna-transcription/package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.runModule [as module] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-es6/node_modules/dist-es6/lib/run.js:13:21)
    at _callee$ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-es6/bin/jasmine.js:45:17)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-es6/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:65:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-es6/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:299:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-es6/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:117:21)
    at step (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-es6/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
```

I have no npm packages installed locally. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. It might be worth noting that I had installed the pre-ES6 versions of node and jasmine, uninstalled them, and installed the ES6 versions. Here is the output of `npm list`:

```
javascript@1.0.0 /home/ken/exercism/javascript
└─┬ jasmine-es6@0.4.3
  ├─┬ babel-runtime@6.26.0
  │ ├── core-js@2.5.1
  │ └── regenerator-runtime@0.11.0
  ├─┬ dist-es6@0.2.5
  │ ├── babel@6.23.0
  │ ├─┬ babel-cli@6.26.0
  │ │ ├─┬ babel-polyfill@6.26.0
  │ │ │ └── regenerator-runtime@0.10.5
  │ │ ├─┬ chokidar@1.7.0
  │ │ │ ├─┬ anymatch@1.3.2
  │ │ │ │ ├─┬ micromatch@2.3.11
  │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ arr-diff@2.0.0
  │ │ │ │ │ │ └── arr-flatten@1.1.0
  │ │ │ │ │ ├── array-unique@0.2.1
  │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ braces@1.8.5
  │ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ expand-range@1.8.2
  │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ fill-range@2.2.3
  │ │ │ │ │ │ │   ├── is-number@2.1.0
  │ │ │ │ │ │ │   ├── isobject@2.1.0
  │ │ │ │ │ │ │   ├─┬ randomatic@1.1.7
  │ │ │ │ │ │ │   │ ├─┬ is-number@3.0.0
  │ │ │ │ │ │ │   │ │ └── kind-of@3.2.2
  │ │ │ │ │ │ │   │ └── kind-of@4.0.0
  │ │ │ │ │ │ │   └── repeat-string@1.6.1
  │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── preserve@0.2.0
  │ │ │ │ │ │ └── repeat-element@1.1.2
  │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ expand-brackets@0.1.5
  │ │ │ │ │ │ └── is-posix-bracket@0.1.1
  │ │ │ │ │ ├── extglob@0.3.2
  │ │ │ │ │ ├── filename-regex@2.0.1
  │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ kind-of@3.2.2
  │ │ │ │ │ │ └── is-buffer@1.1.6
  │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ object.omit@2.0.1
  │ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ for-own@0.1.5
  │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── for-in@1.0.2
  │ │ │ │ │ │ └── is-extendable@0.1.1
  │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ parse-glob@3.0.4
  │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── glob-base@0.3.0
  │ │ │ │ │ │ └── is-dotfile@1.0.3
  │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ regex-cache@0.4.4
  │ │ │ │ │   └─┬ is-equal-shallow@0.1.3
  │ │ │ │ │     └── is-primitive@2.0.0
  │ │ │ │ └─┬ normalize-path@2.1.1
  │ │ │ │   └── remove-trailing-separator@1.1.0
  │ │ │ ├── async-each@1.0.1
  │ │ │ ├── UNMET OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY fsevents@^1.0.0
  │ │ │ ├── glob-parent@2.0.0
  │ │ │ ├─┬ is-binary-path@1.0.1
  │ │ │ │ └── binary-extensions@1.10.0
  │ │ │ ├─┬ is-glob@2.0.1
  │ │ │ │ └── is-extglob@1.0.0
  │ │ │ └─┬ readdirp@2.1.0
  │ │ │   ├─┬ readable-stream@2.3.3
  │ │ │   │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.2
  │ │ │   │ ├── isarray@1.0.0
  │ │ │   │ ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.7
  │ │ │   │ ├── safe-buffer@5.1.1
  │ │ │   │ ├── string_decoder@1.0.3
  │ │ │   │ └── util-deprecate@1.0.2
  │ │ │   └── set-immediate-shim@1.0.1
  │ │ ├── commander@2.11.0
  │ │ ├── fs-readdir-recursive@1.0.0
  │ │ ├─┬ output-file-sync@1.1.2
  │ │ │ ├── graceful-fs@4.1.11
  │ │ │ └── object-assign@4.1.1
  │ │ └─┬ v8flags@2.1.1
  │ │   └── user-home@1.1.1
  │ ├─┬ babel-core@6.26.0
  │ │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.26.0
  │ │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.3
  │ │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.2.1
  │ │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
  │ │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
  │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.1.1
  │ │ │ │ ├── strip-ansi@3.0.1
  │ │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
  │ │ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
  │ │ │ └── js-tokens@3.0.2
  │ │ ├─┬ babel-generator@6.26.0
  │ │ │ ├─┬ detect-indent@4.0.0
  │ │ │ │ └─┬ repeating@2.0.1
  │ │ │ │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.2
  │ │ │ │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.1
  │ │ │ ├── jsesc@1.3.0
  │ │ │ └── trim-right@1.0.1
  │ │ ├── babel-helpers@6.24.1
  │ │ ├── babel-messages@6.23.0
  │ │ ├─┬ babel-register@6.26.0
  │ │ │ ├─┬ home-or-tmp@2.0.0
  │ │ │ │ ├── os-homedir@1.0.2
  │ │ │ │ └── os-tmpdir@1.0.2
  │ │ │ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1
  │ │ │ │ └── minimist@0.0.8
  │ │ │ └── source-map-support@0.4.18
  │ │ ├── babel-template@6.26.0
  │ │ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.26.0
  │ │ │ ├── globals@9.18.0
  │ │ │ └─┬ invariant@2.2.2
  │ │ │   └── loose-envify@1.3.1
  │ │ ├─┬ babel-types@6.26.0
  │ │ │ └── to-fast-properties@1.0.3
  │ │ ├── babylon@6.18.0
  │ │ ├── convert-source-map@1.5.0
  │ │ ├─┬ debug@2.6.9
  │ │ │ └── ms@2.0.0
  │ │ ├── json5@0.5.1
  │ │ ├── lodash@4.17.4
  │ │ ├─┬ minimatch@3.0.4
  │ │ │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.8
  │ │ │   ├── balanced-match@1.0.0
  │ │ │   └── concat-map@0.0.1
  │ │ ├── path-is-absolute@1.0.1
  │ │ ├── private@0.1.8
  │ │ ├── slash@1.0.0
  │ │ └── source-map@0.5.7
  │ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy@1.3.4
  │ │ └── babel-plugin-syntax-decorators@6.13.0
  │ ├── babel-plugin-transform-runtime@6.23.0
  │ ├─┬ babel-preset-latest@6.24.1
  │ │ ├─┬ babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1
  │ │ │ ├── babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants@6.22.0
  │ │ │ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions@6.22.0
  │ │ │ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoped-functions@6.22.0
  │ │ │ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping@6.26.0
  │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes@6.24.1
  │ │ │ │ ├── babel-helper-define-map@6.26.0
  │ │ │ │ ├── babel-helper-function-name@6.24.1
  │ │ │ │ ├── babel-helper-optimise-call-expression@6.24.1
  │ │ │ │ └── babel-helper-replace-supers@6.24.1
  │ │ │ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-computed-properties@6.24.1
  │ │ │ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring@6.23.0
  │ │ │ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-duplicate-keys@6.24.1
  │ │ │ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of@6.23.0
  │ │ │ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-function-name@6.24.1
  │ │ │ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-literals@6.22.0
  │ │ │ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd@6.24.1
  │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs@6.26.0
  │ │ │ │ └── babel-plugin-transform-strict-mode@6.24.1
  │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-systemjs@6.24.1
  │ │ │ │ └── babel-helper-hoist-variables@6.24.1
  │ │ │ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-umd@6.24.1
  │ │ │ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-object-super@6.24.1
  │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters@6.24.1
  │ │ │ │ ├── babel-helper-call-delegate@6.24.1
  │ │ │ │ └── babel-helper-get-function-arity@6.24.1
  │ │ │ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-shorthand-properties@6.24.1
  │ │ │ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread@6.22.0
  │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-sticky-regex@6.24.1
  │ │ │ │ └── babel-helper-regex@6.26.0
  │ │ │ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals@6.22.0
  │ │ │ ├── babel-plugin-transform-es2015-typeof-symbol@6.23.0
  │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-unicode-regex@6.24.1
  │ │ │ │ └─┬ regexpu-core@2.0.0
  │ │ │ │   ├── regenerate@1.3.3
  │ │ │ │   ├── regjsgen@0.2.0
  │ │ │ │   └─┬ regjsparser@0.1.5
  │ │ │ │     └── jsesc@0.5.0
  │ │ │ └─┬ babel-plugin-transform-regenerator@6.26.0
  │ │ │   └── regenerator-transform@0.10.1
  │ │ ├─┬ babel-preset-es2016@6.24.1
  │ │ │ └─┬ babel-plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator@6.24.1
  │ │ │   ├─┬ babel-helper-builder-binary-assignment-operator-visitor@6.24.1
  │ │ │   │ └── babel-helper-explode-assignable-expression@6.24.1
  │ │ │   └── babel-plugin-syntax-exponentiation-operator@6.13.0
  │ │ └─┬ babel-preset-es2017@6.24.1
  │ │   ├── babel-plugin-syntax-trailing-function-commas@6.22.0
  │ │   └─┬ babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator@6.24.1
  │ │     ├── babel-helper-remap-async-to-generator@6.24.1
  │ │     └── babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions@6.13.0
  │ ├─┬ babel-preset-stage-0@6.24.1
  │ │ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-do-expressions@6.22.0
  │ │ │ └── babel-plugin-syntax-do-expressions@6.13.0
  │ │ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-function-bind@6.22.0
  │ │ │ └── babel-plugin-syntax-function-bind@6.13.0
  │ │ └─┬ babel-preset-stage-1@6.24.1
  │ │   ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-class-constructor-call@6.24.1
  │ │   │ └── babel-plugin-syntax-class-constructor-call@6.18.0
  │ │   ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions@6.22.0
  │ │   │ └── babel-plugin-syntax-export-extensions@6.13.0
  │ │   └─┬ babel-preset-stage-2@6.24.1
  │ │     ├── babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import@6.18.0
  │ │     ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-class-properties@6.24.1
  │ │     │ └── babel-plugin-syntax-class-properties@6.13.0
  │ │     ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-decorators@6.24.1
  │ │     │ └─┬ babel-helper-explode-class@6.24.1
  │ │     │   └── babel-helper-bindify-decorators@6.24.1
  │ │     └─┬ babel-preset-stage-3@6.24.1
  │ │       ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-async-generator-functions@6.24.1
  │ │       │ └── babel-plugin-syntax-async-generators@6.13.0
  │ │       └─┬ babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread@6.26.0
  │ │         └── babel-plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread@6.13.0
  │ ├── dedent@0.6.0
  │ ├─┬ fs-extra-promise-es6@0.1.1
  │ │ └─┬ fs-extra@0.26.7
  │ │   ├── jsonfile@2.4.0
  │ │   ├── klaw@1.3.1
  │ │   └── rimraf@2.6.2
  │ └── register-module@0.0.2
  ├── es6-promise@4.1.1
  ├─┬ esnext-async@0.0.9
  │ └── zen-observable@0.3.0
  ├─┬ jasmine@2.8.0
  │ ├── exit@0.1.2
  │ ├─┬ glob@7.1.2
  │ │ ├── fs.realpath@1.0.0
  │ │ ├─┬ inflight@1.0.6
  │ │ │ └── wrappy@1.0.2
  │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.3
  │ │ └── once@1.4.0
  │ └── jasmine-core@2.8.0
  └── node-promise-es6@0.3.2
```

Does anyone have any idea why I can't get this to work? Thanks!

Comment: The clue is `it cannot find a package.json in the directory from which I am running the command`. What's inside `~/exercism/javascript/rna-transcription`? Is there a local package to run tests off of? I've usually had to do `jasmine init` before I can run jasmine tests within a package.

Comment: It's strictly the code and spec file. I tried `jasmine init`, but it still errors out in the same way.